# Computing the probability of a PDF

Tags: probability, density-function

Hi all I have the following question:

Given that the pdf of Y is $\frac{1}{\Pi (1+y^2)}$ for $y\in (-\infty, \infty)$, what's the probability of $Y^{-2}$ being in the interval [1/4,4].

My initial reaction is to simply integrate $Y^{-2}$ with 1/4 and 4 as the limits. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Surround LaTeX code with dollar signs (e.g., `$Y^{-2}$`) to format it.

Comment: @Kodiologist just edited to include that!

Comment: Cool. Now, think about the phrase "integrate $Y^{-2}$". Technically, random variables are functions, but we rarely have need to integrate them directly. That would mean dealing with the sample space, which we usually try to ignore outside the most fundamental parts of probability theory.

Comment: @Kodiologist Hm ok, are you suggesting that I approach the problem differently?

Comment: I'm suggesting that first of all, integrating $Y^{-2}$ isn't what you were actually thinking of doing. You were actually thinking of some variation on integrating the PDF of $Y$.

Comment: @Kodiologist I see, so what I would need to do is actually find the PDF of Y^-2 before I can integrate that. However I don't quite know how to transform the pdf of Y to Y^-2. Do you have any hints?

Comment: I guess there may something wrong with your pdf of $Y$. What do you mean $\Pi (1+y^2)$. Is it $(1+y^2)^n$ or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guide:

We do not need to find the pdf of $Y^2$ explicitly.

We are interested in $$\frac14 \leq Y^{-2} \leq 4$$

Try to solve for $Y$, that is find $a,b,c,d$ such that

$a \leq Y \leq b$ or $c \leq Y \leq d$.

You can then use the pdf of $Y$ to evaluate the probability.

Comment: So I squared the inequality to get $\frac{1}{16} \leq Y \leq 16$. Do i then break this up into two new probability equations?

Comment: Squaring it make things worse isn't it? $\frac1{16} \leq Y^{-4} \leq 16$.

Comment: Rookie mistake on my part, what I need to do is multiply a negative square root. The new inequality should be $2 \leq Y \leq \frac{1}{2}$ or $Y \geq 2$, right?

Comment: The inequality $2 \leq Y \leq \frac12$ is strange as we are claiming that $2$ is smaller or equal to $0.5$ but you are very close now. $Y \geq 2$ is not quite right. For example, $10 \geq 2$ but $\frac14 \leq 10^{-2} \leq 4$ is notr true. After we find an interval, we can always try a few values from the interval to check if we have made a careless mistake. Try to fix the first interval, you are very close to one of the interval now.

Comment: Thanks for your patience so far. Am I allowed to flip the inequality signs to make it a valid inequality? So could I say $2 \geq Y \geq \frac{1}{2}$ or would it be $\frac{1}{2} \leq Y \leq 2$? otherwise I am stumped how to make the inequality a valid one

Comment: Congratulations, you have obtained one of the interval correctly. The rationale for flipping is because $x^{-1}$ is an inverse function. Now to find the other interval, a hint is $(-1)^2 = 1^2$.

Comment: Would the second interval be the negative version? $-2 \leq Y \leq -\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: congratulations. =) you did it. Now you just need to use the pdf of $Y$ to find the corresponding probability. you might want to take advantage of the symmetry of the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience! Statistics is a bit hard for me to grasp, but your guidance definitely made it understandable!